# operand could not be broadcast together with shapes <56962,2> .. error

Tags: python, cross-validation

I try logistic regression classification using "k-fold cross validation" in python.

my code:

```
`import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.model_selection import StratifiedKFold
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix,roc_auc_score    
data = pd.read_csv('xxx.csv')
X = data[["a","b","c",...]]
y = data["Class"]
def get_predictions(clf, X_train, y_train, X_test):
    clf = clf
    clf.fit(X_train,y_train)
    y_pred = clf.predict(X_test)
    y_pred_prob = clf.predict_proba(X_test)
    train_pred = clf.predict(X_train)
    print('train-set confusion matrix:\n', confusion_matrix(y_train,train_pred)) 
    return y_pred, y_pred_prob

skf = StratifiedKFold(n_splits = 5, shuffle = True, random_state = 0)
pred_test_full=0
cv_score=[]
i=1
for train_index, test_index in skf.split(X, y):
    X_train, y_train = X.loc[train_index], y.loc[train_index]
    X_test, y_test = X.loc[test_index], y.loc[test_index]  
    log_cfl = LogisticRegression(C=2);
    log_cfl.fit(X_train, y_train)
    y_pred, y_pred_prob = get_predictions(LogisticRegression(C=2), X_train, y_train, X_test)
    score=roc_auc_score(y_test,log_cfl.predict(X_test))
    print('ROC AUC score: ',score)
    cv_score.append(score)
    pred_test_full = pred_test_full + y_pred_prob
    i+=1`
```

I get error at this line of code:

```
`pred_test_full = pred_test_full + y_pred_prob`
```

For loop runs 2 times. Then in third, I get the error.

`'operands could not be broadcast together with shapes  <56962,2> <5696..'` error.

I couldn't understand what is wrong, could you help to figure out?

Comment: Getting error: `NameError: name 'X' is not defined`

Comment: We need to see get_predictions function

Comment: @Zeynep predict_proba returns len(y) * 2 sized matrix which are the probabilities of both classes, so the shape of pred_test_full doesn't match. Try pred_test_full = np.zeros((len(y), 2)).

Comment: @gunes Sorry I couldn't quite understand. Is this what you mean: `pred_test_full = np.zeros((len(y), 2))
 pred_test_full = pred_test_full+y_pred_prob` I tried but It is not working.